# json output in specific format

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-6

I have data in a tabular format like this:

[image]

I am using Entity Framework in ASP.NET Web API and I want the return in the following format:

```
{
  "empId": 129,
  "mediclaim": [
    {
      "docRemarks": "Mediclaim 2015-16",
      "docReference": "1516.pdf",
      "uploadDate": "28-01-2016 10:53:08"
    }
  ],
  "paySlip": [
    {
      "docRemarks": "December 2015",
      "docReference": "201512.pdf",
      "uploadDate": "28-01-2016 00:59:19"
    },
    {
      "docRemarks": "December 2015",
      "docReference": "201511.pdf",
      "uploadDate": "28-01-2016 00:58:55"
    }
  ]
}
```

If mediclaim & payslip are hard coded, I have a solution on doing this. The problem is I can't do it. Some may have only mediclaims, or only payslips or any other document type defined in `docType` table.

Writing multiple queries by finding `distinct docTypes` for `EmpId = 129` is also a solution. But since the data is going to be huge, I am wondering how this can be achieved using a single query.

Thanks,
Lakshman.

Comment: use `GroupBy` query on `DocTypeName` field